# How to make empty data go last in sort jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "2"
}, {
  "id": "3"
}, {
  "id": "4"
}, {
  "id": "5"
}, {
  "id": "6"
}, {
  "id": "7"
}, {
  "id": "1"
}, {
  "id": ""
}, {
  "id": ""
}, {
  "id": ""
}]

$('.up').click(function() {
  var prop = $(this).closest('th').attr('data-name');
  var data1 = sortResults(data, prop, 'asc')
  console.log(data1)
})
$('.down').click(function() {
  var prop = $(this).closest('th').attr('data-name');
  var data1 = sortResults(data, prop, 'desc')
  console.log(data1)
})


function sortResults(data, prop, asc) {
  console.log("done data " + data)
  console.log("done prop " + prop)
  console.log("done asc " + asc)
  data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (asc)
      return (a[prop] > b[prop]);
    else
      return (b[prop] > a[prop]);
  });
  
  return data;
}
```

```css
.up {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.down {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.filter {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 14px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th data-name='id'>ID <span class='filter'><span class='up'></span><span class='down'></span></span>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

1. How to make id with empty value value go last from `.sort()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sort` callback is incorrect. It needs to return a negative number if the first item goes before the second, a positive number if the second goes before the first, or 0 if they're "the same." Instead, your function is returning booleans, which will get coerced to 1 (if true) or 0 (if false), which won't sort things correctly.

`String#localeCompare` is handy for sorting strings. It will consider `""` "earlier" than anything with content, though, so we have to special-case that:

```
function sortResults(data, prop, asc) {
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var vala = a[prop],
        valb = b[prop];
    if (!vala) {
        // vala is blank -- if valb is also blank, return 0;
        // otherwise, return 1 to put vala *after* valb
        return !valb ? 0 : 1;
    }
    if (!valb) {
        // valb is blank, return -1 to put it *after* vala
        return -1;
    }
    if (asc) {
      // Ascending sort, use localeCompare
      return vala.localeCompare(valb);
    }
    // Descending sort, use localeCompare the other way around
    return valb.localeCompare(vala);
  });

  return data;
}
```

---

Side note: `Array#sort` sorts the array *in place*, so no need for `data = data.sort(...)`.

Comment: the explanation is very important for my understanding +1 i need 7 mins to accept

Comment: i have one question why is it when i click on down it is still making the list start from 1.. just noticed it is always asc [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j8wrshws/)

Comment: @BrownmanRevival: Primarily because you were using *strings* for your `asc` flag, but treating it as a boolean. Both `'asc'` and `'desc'` are *truthy* values, `if (asc)` when it's one of those strings will always be true. Use a real flag instead: https://jsfiddle.net/j8wrshws/2/ 2. I had a typo in my answer that you copied to that fiddle (the last line should be `return valb.localeCompare(vala);` not `return vala.localeCompare(vala);`). Also fixed in that fiddle (and above).